# I believe a portion of a paper I am coauthoring is false

Tags: publications, ethics

I have mildly contributed to a research project which is now ready for publication.
However, I am convinced the treatment of the experimental data is wrong.

I shared my concerns with the PI of this project and shown him why I believe this was not correct. Yet, I only made him doubt and he still wants to publish it as it is. This treatment of the data is not necessary to reach the conclusion of the paper which still holds with more standard data analysis, but it looks less fancy. Now what should I do ?

- should I go ahead and work on the publication ?
- should I withdraw from this project (which is a side project for me) ?

On the one hand I still believe the conclusion of the paper is true and I could use an additional publication on my CV. On the other hand I feel it is dishonest to publish something which I believe is not true.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. Please be aware that we cannot weigh different aspects (ethics, your CV) for you. You probably get a more helpful answer if you ask for ways to achieve a specific goal such as ways to get your part published without facing ethical issues. Note that you can [edit] your answer.

Comment: Your sense of academic integrity is more valuable than a line in your CV. If you feel strongly enough about it to post this question, perhaps you should drop out. Doing so might cause the PI to reconsider the issue. It is of course easy for me to say this. Only you know all of the issues involved.

Comment: I would also say it depends on your field. For a straight philosophy (the discipline) paper, don't have your name on anything you don't fully endorse. For a 1000+ author physics paper, I would never assume any author of the paper endorses its every word as dogma.

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be giving two stories: you note that you 'still believe the conclusion of the paper is true' but you then note that 'it is dishonest to publish something which I believe is not true'.  If the issue is simply the handling of the data analysis (with alternative paths leading to the same conclusions through more or less fancy approaches), I might suggest a compromise. Add a footnote at the presentation of that analysis indicating that conclusions remain even under a more conservative statistical analysis.  If the journal allows, you can elaborate a bit there.  That way, you've solidified that you understand there are multiple approaches, but the conclusion is robust to that. This might be even more convincing.

Answer (score 4):

Before signing or withdrawing, I prefer to keep discussing those matters until a decision is taken which everyone can defend. If this isn't possible you will have to weight the pro's and con's, and how you feel about having a paper with your name that you cannot stand behind (if that is the case).

One option could be to not be named as author, but instead in the acknowledgement section - especially if your role was a minor one.